# Formatting of JUnit Messages

Tags: junit, junit5

Using JUnit `assertEquals()`, I am comparing strings which may differ in whitespace/control characters.
In particular, '\r\n' vs. '\n'.
When the strings differ in this way the error output from `assertEquals()` is difficult to interpret for a few reasons.

- They are whitespace characters and are not suitable for visual inspection
- The \r character causes output to be overwritten.

This example shows how you'd normally test a string if you wouldn't have any special chars within
*/

```java
@Test
public void testIfTheCarriageReturned()
{
    final String expected = "we're taking\r\n the hobbits\r\n to Isengard!";
    final String actual = "we're taking\n the hobbits\n to Isengard!";
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

This example correctly determines that the strings differ but the
output from JUnit does not make it clear how they differ (whitespace not being treated in any special way).

Is there a way to cause JUnit to produce more suitable output?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a concrete example of what you are talking about. Explain why/how it is difficult to read the generated error message. Keep in mind that you can provide your own error message with the string argument of `assertEquals()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I guess this not about formatting but rather about writing your tests properly. I've never cared about the new features of Junit5, therefore there might be a new super smart way to achieve this, but yeah:

```java
@Test
public void testIfTheCarriageReturned()
{
    /**
     * This is how you'd normally test string if you wouldn't have any special chars within
     */
    final String expected = "we're taking\r\n the hobbits\r\n to Isengard!";
    final String linuxGuy = "we're taking\n the hobbits\n to Isengard!";
    //assertEquals(expected, linuxGuy);

    /**
     * Just do it charwise...
     */
    for(int i = 0; i<expected.length(); i++)
    {
        assertEquals("Character differed at index "+i,Character.getName(expected.charAt(i)), Character.getName(linuxGuy.charAt(i)));
    }
}
```

This basically just gets the name for the character and compares whether they are equal at the same index.

This will lead to the following output:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: Character differed at index 12 expected:<[CARRIAGE RETURN (CR])> but was:<[LINE FEED (LF])>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:117)
```

Just to add:
This will lead to a passed test when the actual String is longer than the expected String. You could either check the length afterwards or use the assertEquals method on the two strings after the loop. A matter of taste, I'd probably prefer the latter.

Comment: You could also call `String.getBytes()` and then use [assertArrayEquals](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertArrayEquals-byte:A-byte:A-)

Comment: In Jupiter (JUnit 5) the optional message String must be the last parameter of assertEquals().

Comment: Your example illustrates the issue correctly. Do you mind if I copy the appropriate portion of it into the question? The solution works so I will accept it. The solution  implies a different intent i.e. checking a strings vs. checking characters.

Comment: @phreed Do as you please, if I'd mind about anything getting copied from here, I wouldn't post here 